# Mule + cxf + OuboundInterceptor does not call

Tags: cxf, mule, interceptor

I use cxf to call a remote web service.(integrate with mule and spring).

I want to add an Outbound Interceptor to my classes which add some headers to my request.

My config is :

```
<chaining-router>
    <cxf:outbound-endpoint ref="facilityAuthenticationCoreEndpoint">
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:bean class="com.mycompany.webservice.client.transformer.SoapHeaderEnricher"/>
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
    </cxf:outbound-endpoint>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint address="vm://serviceResponseJob"/>
</chaining-router>
```

`SoapHeaderEnricher` class is extending from `AbstractSoapInterceptor` and has a `handleMessage(Message message)` method.

```
public class SoapHeaderEnricher extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {
    public SoapHeaderEnricher() {
    }

    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        do something here.
    }
}
```

But when i run the service, the web service is called and a wrong response is received cause of my `handleMessage` method is never called.

Is there anybody who knows the trick?

Sincerely.

Comment: So where is the class ? how can we check the issue without seeing your class

Comment: `chaining-router`? Is that Mule 2?

Comment: Hi david. Yeah, it's mule 2.5? Is there any idea?

Comment: Hi Anirban. The class is SoapHeaderEnricher and it's code is here. What do u mean by where is the class? Thx.